# Rails left joins and inner joins in one query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

The question is how can I find all records without associations **OR** with associations that have field not equal to given string:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :administration_groups
  has_many :administrations, through: :administration_groups
end

class AdministrationGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :administration
  belongs_to :group
end

class Administration < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :administration_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :administration_groups
end
```

So how can I get all groups, which have no administrations, or have administrations but with 'administration_type' not equal to 'type1'?

```
groups_1 = Group.left_joins(:administration_groups).where(administration_groups: {id: nil})

groups_2 = Group.joins(administration_groups: [:administration]).where.not(administrations: {administration_type: params[:type]})
```

I have this two queries, but I can't combine them to get results which are needed. Appreciate any help

Comment: do you want to combine both records of `groups_1` and `groups_2` ?

Comment: @Vishal yep. But to have only one query

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the ids from those 2 queries and you can use `or` to merge together `ActiveRecord::Relations` like so:

```
Group.where.not(id: 
  Group.joins(:administration_groups)
  .pluck(:id)
).or(
Group.where(id: 
  Group
    .joins(administration_groups: :administration)
       .where.not(administrations: {administration_type: params[:type]}).pluck(:id)
))
```

Which should result in a query similar to

```
 SELECT 
   [groups].*
 FROM 
   [groups] 
 WHERE
   ([groups].[id] NOT IN (
      SELECT 
         [groups].[id] 
      FROM 
         [groups] 
         INNER JOIN [administration_groups] 
           ON [administration_groups].[group_id] = [groups].[id])
   ) OR (
     [groups].[id] IN ( 
     SELECT 
         [groups]. [id] 
     FROM 
         [groups] 
         INNER JOIN [administration_groups] 
            ON [administration_groups].[group_id] = [groups].[id]
         INNER JOIN [administrations] 
           ON [administrations].[id] = [administration_groups].[administration_id] 
     WHERE 
           [administrations].[administration_type] <> YOUR_PARAMS_TYPE)
  )
```

Additionally this too may work:

```
Group.where.not(id: 
  Group
    .joins(administration_groups: :administration)
       .where(administrations: {administration_type: params[:type]}).pluck(:id))
```

Which will result in

```
SELECT 
  [groups].*
FROM 
  [groups]
WHERE 
  [groups].[id] NOT IN (
     SELECT 
         [groups]. [id] 
     FROM 
         [groups] 
         INNER JOIN [administration_groups] 
            ON [administration_groups].[group_id] = [groups].[id]
         INNER JOIN [administrations] 
           ON [administrations].[id] = [administration_groups].[administration_id] 
     WHERE 
           [administrations].[administration_type] = YOUR_PARAMS_TYPE
  )
```

Since the INNER JOIN on [administration_groups] will already remove the NULL values and then the type check will include the other IDs you do not want to include.

Comment: `ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:left_outer_joins, :references])`

Comment: @A.Chile updated with a different solution using id based sub queries as the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
groups = Group.left_joins(:administrations).where(
  "administrations.id is NULL OR
   administrations.administration_type != ?", params[:type]
)
```

Comment: This query does not return groups which have no administrations

Comment: @A.Chile I have updated the answer, Please check it now.